# How to compile Angular 12 library with recursive components?

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

Tldr: how to compile angular library with recursive components?

Prehistory: I have an application which purpose is to display complex forms. First you have to create an array of fields, then you pass the array to `app-form` component and it creates components that correspond to type of a certain field. Like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <app-input *ngIf="item.type === 'input'"></app-input>
  <app-checkbox *ngIf="item.type === 'checkbox'"></app-checkbox>
  <app-tablist *ngIf="item.type === 'tablist'" [form]="field"></app-tablist>
  <app-cardlist *ngIf="item.type === 'cardlist'" [form]="field"></app-cardlist>
  ...
</div>
```

This is a simplified `app-form` template. As you can see there are basic field types - inputs, checkboxes, etc - and there are complex field types - tablists cardlists. Complex fields have references to `app-form` in their templates, here is tablist' template for example:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let form_field of form.fields; index as i;">
    <mat-card>
      <app-form [form]="form_field.value"></app-form>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

There are recursive components: `form > tablist > form`, they never caused troubles

Now I need to extract `app-form` to library so I can use it throughout many applications. But when I build the library it says *"One or more import cycles would need to be created to compile this component, which is not supported by the current compiler configuration"*. Is there anything I can do about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like at the moment there is no way Ivy can build libraries with recursive components, there is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35602) about it in angular github. They say the problem should be resolved after adding sideEffects: true to library' package.json, but it doesn't seem to have any effect for me, so I ended up moving all the 2nd level components to the parent component: all the components that have form in their templates are now defined in form.component file

Answer (score 1):

In the [official documentation on this problem](https://angular.io/errors/NG3003#libraries), they only give tips to solve the problem instead of giving options to bypass the error, so I'm afraid it's not possible...